What would be the opa policy for accessung a special path?
I am new to OPA and have tried a lot to get this result:
I want OPA to only allow access to /index. I am working on minikube with docker installed and I have a mciroservice as webserver. But the following rego does not work:
package istio.authz
import rego.v1

allow if {
    http_request.method == "GET"
    http_request.path == "/index"
}

I installed istio and OPA using the quick_start file from the OPA website.
When I try to go to /index this is the result:
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination

But unfortunatelly I don't get how to change the rego ...

If bundle api is not used, OPA refers policy from application namespace configmap "opa-policy" and its loaded to "opa-istio" container as volume mount.   More details are there in opa tutorial.

In typical deployments the policy would either be built into the OPA
container image or it would fetched dynamically via the Bundle API.
ConfigMaps are used in this tutorial for test purposes.

An import statment is missing policy.rego for http_request which will result in policy error.  Please use updated policy as below.
package istio.authz

import input.attributes.request.http as http_request
import rego.v1

allow if {
    http_request.method == "GET"
    http_request.path == "/index"
}

